# OneDrive for Business Login--Does not recognize UN or PW

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

Sharepoint Online 365--I recently enabled 2FA for my company's sharepoint O365 site. Now, certain users are having sync issues with OneDrive for Business.  When they try to login when prompted by ODFB their .onmicrosoft.com email addresses and passwords are not recognized.  Has anyone else had this issue?  I have reset passwords, to no avail.  There doesn't seem to be a lot of other users experiencing this in other SP communities.